# C# DateTime.TryParse makes me confused

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am using `DateTime.TryParse` method in my program to judge if a string value is `DateTime`, then I notice this:

```
DateTime.TryParse("9.08", out DateTime dt)
// true
DateTime.TryParse("2.52", out DateTime dt)
// false
```

Why would this happened ?

Comment: What did you expect for `2.52`? 52 of february? Or second day of month `52`? `true` indicates whether the conversion succeeded, `false` indicates it did not

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560377/datetime-parse-can-format-unusual-format-strings/

Comment: It must be treated as 9(month)8(date), ToT

Comment: Probably you want to check if your string matches a specific format? In that case you can use `TryParseExact` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)  is parsed information in the current `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture.

> Because the DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse the string representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture, trying to parse a particular string across different cultures can either fail or return different results. If a specific date and time format will be parsed across different locales

In some cultures, `DateTime` separator is `.` rather than  `/`.

On my computer.

`DateTime.TryParse` will Parse `"9.08"`  be this year `'09/08'`,  `2018/09/08` is a valid `datetime`, so it's `true`.

`DateTime.TryParse` will Parse `"2.52"` be this year `'02/52'`, but there isn't 52nd days on February, `2018/02/52` isn't a valid `DateTime`, so it will be `false`.

I would use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)  to Parse DateTime because you can set your `CultureInfo` and `Parse` DateTime string be parameters and ensure that conforms to your expected format.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("09.08",
                       "MM.dd",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out dt);
```

Comment: It depends on culture settings. The first is `2018-08-09` on my German machine.

Comment: Or create your own `var customFormatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo { DateSeparator = "." };` and use it in `DateTime.TryParse("9.08", customFormatInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt)`

Answer (score 1):

As per [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

As it couldn't parse `"2.52"` to any valid date, it returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Except you are trying to understand every time string conversion of .NET
Otherwise, you should not able to answer "why exactly would that happened?"

DateTime.TryParse is just a simple condition handling to prevent you getting an error when you do

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dateString)
```

Thus, `DateTime.TryParse = false` means you should not do `Convert.ToDateTime` to that string.

Oppositely, if a string to `DateTime.TryParse = true`, then it means that string should match the expectation of .NET date string (it means .NET know how to convert that string to DateTime).